# Swift: Chaining String/Substring methods yields 'ambiguous use of' errors. Fix or alternative?

Tags: swift, string, nsstring, substring, ambiguous

I'm trying to do the most basic string manipulation using Swift. It looks like String provides everything I need, even though it relies on Substring intermediate results. So this works

```
let myString = "0123456789"
let mySubstring = myString.dropFirst(2)
print(mySubstring.dropLast(2))
```

It successfully yields "234567" as a Substring.

However, when I attempt to chain the calls...

```
print(myString.dropFirst(2).dropLast(2))
```

I get the following error...

```
  9> print(myString.dropFirst(2).dropLast(2))
error: repl.swift:9:7: error: ambiguous use of 'dropFirst'
print(myString.dropFirst(2).dropLast(2))
      ^

Swift.Collection:39:17: note: found this candidate
    public func dropFirst(_ n: Int) -> Self.SubSequence
                ^

Swift.Sequence:20:17: note: found this candidate
    public func dropFirst(_ n: Int) -> AnySequence<Self.Element>
                ^
```

So it seems like the compiler is understandably having trouble inferring which dropFirst method to invoke because it is defined twice with different return types.

Is there a way around this? Is this just really poor API design on Apple's part? I'm trying to just get a nice easy to read and concise bit of code. I can also make it work by resorting to NSString but this seems wasteful and even more verbose and obtuse.

**UPDATE:**

I am able to get a better result by adding *as Substring* after the chain as in...

```
print(myString.dropFirst(2).dropLast(2) as Substring)
```

...since that disambiguates the overloaded methods. I would still love to see a more concise solution. Thanks.

Comment: Did you see the error output in my message? It doesn't work in Xcode 9 and Swift 4. What version of Xcode and Swift are you using @vacawama? Or is this because of the order of calls? Perhaps dropLast isn't overloaded.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks. I missed that when I read it. ;-)

Comment: This ambiguity is fixed by [this pull request](https://github.com/apple/swift/pull/12029), your code compiles as expected in the latest dev snapshot.

Comment: Awesome!  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you define the return type, it has no trouble resolving which function to use. There are a number of ways to do this, such as:

```
let mySubstring: Substring = myString.dropFirst(2).dropLast(2)
```

Of course, as you say, you can insert this `Substring` type within the expression:

```
let mySubstring = (myString.dropFirst(2) as Substring).dropLast(2)
```

Comment: Thanks. Seems that using this or including "as Substring" somewhere in the chain solves the problem. In fact, just adding as Substring to the very end of the chain seems to disambiguate much longer chains.

Comment: Yep. I think it's cleaner this way (I hate inserting syntactic noise within the expression unless I have to), but, like I said, there are a number of ways of doing this. But I've added this other permutation to the answer.

Comment: Or just initialize a new string and apply dropLast on it. String(myString.dropFirst(2)).dropLast(2)

Comment: Yeah, I thought about that (and Vadian suggested precisely this), but it strikes me as weird to get a `Substring`, convert that to a `String` and then get `Substring` of that `String`. You've baked in the (admittedly, modest) overhead of that intermediate `String`. If you wanted a `String` at the end, I'd stay within `Substring`, and then do String conversion at the end, e.g. `String(myString.dropFirst(2).dropLast(2) as Substring)`.

Comment: Agreed. I am trying to eliminate overhead here. This is for some inner loop code in a low latency/high throughput situation. Substrings are optimized for this. Converting multiple times to String will be out of the question.

Comment: @Chuck:  If the final target is a String, then `String(myString.dropFirst(2).dropLast(2)...)` would work as well, with only one conversion at the end.

Comment: @MartinR it depends on the string of operations. It works with my example in the original problem. But in general it doesn't. E.g. Try this artificial example String(s.dropFirst(2).dropLast(2).dropFirst(1)).

Comment: @Chuck: You are right, so that does not help. I had tested it with `String(s.dropFirst(2).dropLast(2).dropFirst(1).dropLast(2))` which does compile.

Answer (score 1):

Surprisingly, it works if you reverse the order and do the `dropLast` first:

```
print(myString.dropLast(2).dropFirst(2))
```

Comment: This is interesting and due to dropLast not being overloaded (just looked it up). Unfortunately, this was just a short example of much longer chains I am working with so careful selection of order of operations won't always work. I guess I'll just have to live with it and disambiguate as needed.

Comment: Don't be afraid to create intermediate results with `let`.  Any compiler worth a darn will optimize that away and it makes it easier to debug what is happening.

Comment: Yes, I understand that. I'm just looking for conciseness. In the actual code where I encountered this problem I had to create about a dozen intermediate results with let. It just makes things harder to read and maintain. I don't have to do this is Java, Python, C++, Scala, Ruby, C#, etc...